# Adding ngModel to angular datepicker input using a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, directive, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to create a ui that is generated using a schema object containing properties and validation etc. I need to set ngModel on my ui controls using a directive as a result. The value of ngModel is a string which represents a property path on a schema object on the scope.

I have this working for standard inputs, but when using angular ui datepicker i get the following error.

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'myModel', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=myModel
at http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:78:20
at getControllers (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:6054:39)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:6225:55)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:5634:37)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:5637:33)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:5637:33)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:5539:46)
at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:5653:37)
at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:6245:36)
at Object.ngIfWatchAction [as fn] (http://localhost:3000/javascripts/angular.js:18316:29)

<input class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd-MMM-yyyy" my-model="" is open="property.calOpen" close-text="Close" ng-model="editModel.Person.Detail.DateOfBirth">
```

The directive I have is below.

```
angular.module('MyDirectives',[])
.directive('myModel', function($compile , $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',                       
        priority:0,

        link: function(scope,element, attr) {

            if(angular.isDefined(attr.ngModel))return;
            var field = scope.path ? scope.path + '.' + scope.key : scope.key;
            attr.$set("ngModel", "editModel." + field);

            console.log("in directive");
            $timeout(function(){
                $compile(element)(scope);
            });
        }
    };
```

As the value for ngModel lives on the scope, I believe I need the link function rather than compile. I have tried adding `Require: ?ngModel` to the directive which makes no difference. Also tried increasing priority, but this changes error to
`Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'input', can't be found!`

If I remove the `$timeout(function(){}` surrounding `$compile(element)(scope)` 2 popup calendars appear overlayed. This is noticable when navigating through months.

Any Ideas

UPDATE: see link
[plkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/R3CmbensSgDGf9wNFBwS?p=preview)

Comment: How about a fiddle...?

Comment: plnkr added, see link.

Comment: Sorry, but it is way too messed (as far as I can tell). You are using your template circularly. And adding `ngModel` later on (meaning after the other directives (e.g. `datapicker`) have been compiled) won't help either. I suggest you try to simplify things (a lot) (although I am not sure how exactly). Sorry I can't help more :)

Comment: Thankyou, but that isnt really any help to me. I keep hitting this issue whenever i need to dynamically set ng-model where other directives are used which need the ng-model value.#help!

Comment: If there is a directive that require's ngModel you could try having it's compile function add the ngModel directive (but it must be run before ngModel's compile - you have to take a look into priorities).

Comment: I agree, the compile function would be the place (and time), however the value I need to set ngModel to is on the scope object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new two-way binding to a local scope variable (scope: true).
Use $parse to locate the property at the path.

See [updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0seMHc9UAilGKcN5GzIy?p=preview)